# deccryptage php

Tags: php

i try de decrypt my file ,but i have this message

> Warning: mcrypt_cbc() [function.mcrypt-cbc]: Size of key is too large
>   for this algorithm in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/test.php on line 32

```
<?php

   $key = md5("Test");


           //fonction decode
           function decode($pass_coder)
           {
           $pass_str = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_TripleDES,$key, $pass_coder, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
           return $pass_str;
           }

     echo (decode($pass_coder));
    >
```

i use this function to encrypt my file

```
public void Encrypt(XmlDocument doc, string rootTag, string password)
       {
           // Transform password to MD5 hash value
           ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
           MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
           byte[] md5val = md5.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(password));

           // Create key and use MD5 hash value as key
           TripleDES key = TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
           key.Key = md5val;

           // Encrypt data
           EncryptedXml ec = new EncryptedXml(doc);
           ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
           foreach (XmlElement el in doc.GetElementsByTagName(rootTag))
           {
               byte[] data = ec.EncryptData(el, key, false);
               EncryptedData ed = new EncryptedData();
               ed.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;
               ed.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml
.XmlEncTripleDESUrl);
               ed.CipherData = new CipherData();
               ed.CipherData.CipherValue = data;
               list.Add(new object[] { el, ed });
           }

           // Write encrypted data to XML document
           foreach (object[] obj in list)
               EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement((XmlElement)obj[0], (
EncryptedData)obj[1], false);
       }
```

Comment: As error messages go "Size of key is too large for this algorithm " seems fairly conclusive.

Comment: when i show my md5($key) is 0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b ,i need use this key to decrypte

Comment: What's wrong with the "the key is too large" idea?

Comment: yes , i want soluion to decrypt my file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've missed your problem entirely, but what I suspect you are trying to do, is not possible.  You cannot decrypt something that has been hashed with MD5.  You can compare and eventually come to the conclusion that string_xxx == string_yyy if the MD5 hashes match when using the same salt ...

Comment: i just use md5 to encrypt my key and after  i will decrypt my data with triple DES